# No moudle named roocket

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

hello guys i have a problem with a tutorial which im seeing since qurantine has started and i really need a big help into solving it.
story is i lost some of my files or accidently deleted them , so i used the files for the project which they have into zipfiles but for this projects i keep getting this error while im trying to run local server this is the error after using py manage.py makemigrations
(( its a big error so i just copied end of it ))

````
    File "c:\users\navid\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, 
    in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'roocket'```

i think it must be something with bootstrap so i started to see if bootstrap is installed or not and the results for the project directory are:

`asgiref==3.2.7
astroid==2.3.3
beautifulsoup4==4.9.0
colorama==0.4.3
Django==3.0.5
django-bootstrap4==1.1.1
django-jalali==3.3.0
django-jalali-date==0.3.1
isort==4.3.21
jdatetime==3.6.2
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
psycopg2==2.8.5
pylint==2.4.4
pytz==2019.3
six==1.14.0
soupsieve==2.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
wrapt==1.11.2`
````

Comment: install that module using 'pip install roocket'

Comment: @Maharshi roocket is not a builtin module its actually the name of the other program which i got codes from